# Is Self Closing Tag or Void Element an opening tag and closing tag combined in HTML5?

Tags: html

Is the self-closing tag or void element basically an opening and closing tag combined into one tag in HTML5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

It is a regular start tag, with an optional "/" at the end for people trapped with XML syntax.

The end tag is just forbidden for the element type.

Comment: So does HTML5 allow it because it allows valid XML syntax as well?